# Simplifying Multiple neighbouring Polygons, removing gaps and overlaps

Tags: polygon, javascript, algorithm, simplify

My main goal is to simplify multiple polygons, avoiding overlaps and gaps between them.

My initial approach was:

1. Find intersections for each polygon
   so that I end up with an array of polygons, each having a number of intersections.

Example: `[
{polygon:{feature}, intersections:[linestring,linestring]},
{polygon:{feature}, intersections:[linestring,linestring, linestring]},
{polygon:{feature}, intersections:[linestring]}
]`

2. Assuming a polygon can be represented by its intersections and external lines (e.g. lines no intersecting with any other polygon).

   - Slice a polygon into multiple linestrings.
   - Simplify each individual linestring
   - Concatenate the linestring to form a polygon

Example:

- Polygon A = simplify(A1) + simplify(A2) + simplify(Polygon A - (A1 + A2))
- Polygon B = simplify(B1) + simplify(Polygon B - B1)
- Polygon C = simplify(C1) + simplify(Polygon C - C1)

where A1 = B1 and A2 = C1

[image]

My question is, is this a good way to simplify multiple neighbouring polygons, or could you recommend a library or and algorithm for this task?